# узнать абсолютный путь к файлу php

Tags: php

Есть файл в корне сайта, например `/var/www/html/mysite/html/conf.php`,но полный путь к нему мне заранее не известен,известно только его название, как сделать `include` этого файла *conf.php* из файла, который выполняется в `/html/img/conf/res.php`

Comment: а это разве не «абсолютный путь» — `/html/conf.php`? внесите, пожалуйста, ясность в текст вопроса, нажав [edit]

Comment: это ведь был не абсольтный путь к файлу, а только от корня сайта, на сколько я понимаю

Comment: ну так припишите слева путь к корню сайта (т.н. *document root*).

Comment: document root показывает папку, которая по умолчанию в apache /var/www/html/, но что делать, если корень сайта в папке /var/www/html/mysite/html/

Comment: возникает подозрение, что вы пытаетесь решить какую-то неозвученную в вопросе проблему. начните лучше с начала, а не с конца.

Comment: ок, сейчас немного подправлю вопрос, может в самом деле, неясно задал его

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Comment: эта функция возвращает путь только до /var/www/html, а html/mysite/... не показывает

Comment: @diego_costa, [пруф](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php), там сказано "которая указана в конфигурационном файле сервера". Это замечательно, что Вы построили такое хитрое дерево директорий и вложили в него какой-то свой смысл. Но как программа-то об этом узнает?) мысли прочитает?

Comment: если б я заранее знал, что мне надо будет это делать) выходит, что нужно править файл конфиг сервера, чтобы получить доступ к корню через document_root?